# how to convert base64 string image to blob in android?

Tags: android

I have a Base64 string image .I want to convert it into blob type and save it in database..
I have

```
String base64Image="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAACgCAYAAADzcGmMAAAACSV...";
```

This is what I tried..

```
 byte[] byteImage=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(befImage.getBytes());

json.put("during_unloading_photo", byteImage);
```

where json is my JSONObject and 
during_unloading_photo is the column name which is blob type.

Comment: Please don't change the question in such a way that its meaning is totally different and existing answers do no longer fit. If you have another question open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

for saving blob into `DataBase` you have to convert your `base64 satring` image to `Byte[]` and then you can save `byte[]` into `db`.
for converting `base64 string`to bitmap

```
 public static Bitmap decodeBase64Profile(String input) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (input != null) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

and now you can convert this `Bitmap` to `Byte[]` Like:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap!=null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

then finally you can save this Byte[] to Db.make sure your column name have `type` with `blob`

enjoy your code:)-

Answer (score 0):

`getBytes` gives you the bytes of the string, it does not do base64 decoding. You will need to use a Base64 decoder to do the conversion. A little search will show up several options you can use.

Comment: I tried using  byte[] byteImage=Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);                                                  but its nt working..

Comment: Seems you used `android.util.Base64`, right? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I used android.util.Base64. I am trying to get a image from mobile database which is stored as Base64 String and convert it into into blob type so that i can save it in main database.

Comment: I used byte[] byteImg=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(befImage.getBytes());       dato.put("beforeUnloadingPhoto",byteImg );

Comment: Even after using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64 I am not able to sync the byteImg to database..